# Flask app unaccessible from chrome behind proxy

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, flask, proxy

I am working on a Flask application that is launched as follows on a distant server:

`app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)`

The symptoms are the following:

- I can access `server_IP:5000/ping` with any browser from my home computer
- I can access `server_IP:5000/ping` with Firefox from my company computer that is behind a proxy with default "network" setting.
- I can access `server_IP:5000/ping` with any browser (including Chrome) from my company computer when I specify system-wide proxy settings in the "network" tab (ubuntu)
- I **cannot access** `server_IP:5000/ping` **with Chrome** from my company computer that is behind a proxy when I don't specify the proxy. Instead, I get: `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`

Does someone have a suggestion as to why this might be happening and how to fix it? I am looking for a fix on the server side as I don't want the solution to involve potential users of the application having to change their Chrome settings...

**EDIT**

It turns out **putting the application on the 8080 port solved the issue** for me. Although this issue was certainly linked to the company proxy, I have trouble understanding why the same address could be accessible by Firefox and not Chrome...

**EDIT 2**

It turns out my Firefox had a manual proxy configuration I wasn't aware of (and not chrome) which explains why one browser could access the application and not the other. The original problem is probably linked to the main **proxy blocking requests on 5000 ports**.

Comment: Can you access other web sites with Chrome? Why do you think that is?

Comment: Most websites are accessible through chrome and those that are banned by the proxy and are unaccessible in Chrome are usually also unaccessible in Firefox. As I mentionned in the edit, it seems like my issue is linked to the combination of 1) using Chrome 2) behind a proxy 3) asking for the port 5000 of an address...

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Firefox's "default" setting.  Is it either "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network" or "Use system proxy settings"?  The wording may be a little different on your version of Firefox.  When you said " default "network" setting", is that same/similar to "Auto-detect proxy settings for this network"?

If your company is as paranoid as mine, absolutely no traffic from inside can connect to the outside without passing thru the proxy server (so they can control it; no facebook, porn sites, etc).  And there ain't no way of getting around that.  Everything that needs to connect to external must somehow support & be configured to use the proxy server.  It is just a question of how.  Sometimes it's explicitly configured; sometimes it's detected or inherited from the system.  I strongly suspect this is the case for your Firefox.

Where are your users?  Users internal to your company probably already have the necessary config, else they wouldn't even be able to get to google.com, etc.  Users external to your company won't need to pass thru your company's proxy and so won't need your company's proxy config.

Comment: It turns out that Firefox had a manual proxy configuration I wasn't aware of which explains why it was able to access the application when Chrome wasn't. In the end, I assume my proxy was blocking port 5000 requests. Putting the application on port 8080 solved the issue.